# Applying a function on each row of dataframe and ignoring the exception (if any)

Tags: python, exception, lambda

Am trying to run an apply lambda function on each row of a dataframe.
However, the function can return certain exceptions/errors.
How can i bypass/ignore those exceptions, and continue execution?
I tried using an if else within the apply function but it did not go well.

Here is my piece of code:

```
df['IV'] = df.apply(lambda row: iv(row['Close_x'], row['Close_y'], row['Strike'], row['TTE_x'], 0, flag='c'))
```

Comment: If you are expecting the operation to throw, wouldn't it be better to define a normal function instead?

Comment: I am using a function from the py_vollib library, and the iv function would throw an exception on some rows, but i just want to ignore or enter some junk value if it encounters, and continue with next row

Comment: Could you help when you say defining a normal function?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen an elegant way of suppressing exceptions in a lambda, though it is very rare that you'd really need to. As mentioned in thefourtheye's comment, you can do this though

```python
def myfunc(row):
    try:
        iv(row['Close_x'], row['Close_y'], row['Strike'], row['TTE_x'], 0, flag='c')
    except ExceptionThatIVSometimesThrows as e:
        print("Error on row", row.name)

df['IV'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but its apparently returning a key error, why would that be ?
KeyError: 'Close_x'
 i have checked this column does not have any nulls

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe we need to provide the `axis=1` argument to apply so that we get rows and not columns. See edit.

Comment: ah yes you mean in the apply function

Comment: ah yes, that's what I meant to do.

Comment: Hi, Could you tell if we need to assign the output to the column for each row ?
df['IV'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1) inputs None in the column
If i try to just run the myfunc with a print statement, it does print the output of iv.
However it does not populate the df